# How to get coords of a Tkinter Canvas Image

Tags: python, image, tkinter, get, coordinates

So my problem and question is:
Is it possible to somehow get the second coordinates from an Image.
I created a game in Tkinter with canvas and the rectangle object for example has 4 coords x1,x2,y1,y2 the game works fine it is a brick breaker game.
Now i decided to add images for the ball and the paddle but it seems that it doesnt work to get the second coordinates and it makes the game kinda buggy since i dont get x2 and y2.
Is there a way to get these coordinates?

Heres an example for the game without the pictures:

```
        def hit_paddle(self, pos):
        paddle_pos = self.gamerootCanvas.coords(self.paddle.id)
        if pos[1] >= paddle_pos[1] and pos[1] <= paddle_pos[3]:
            if pos[0] >= paddle_pos[0] and pos[0] <= paddle_pos[2]:
               return True
        return False
```

and basically if i add pictures im not able to use  paddlepos[2] and [3] anymore since [0] is x1 [1] is y1 and [2] and [3] are x2 and y2.

Comment: It's called `bbox`, try `= self.gamerootCanvas.bbox(self.paddle.id)`

Comment: Thanks you so much it worked!